# Mobile traffic sniffing using Cain

Tags: sniffer, arp-spoofing

As far as I know - and please correct me if I'm wrong - [Cain](http://www.oxid.it/) does not support WiFi cards. So if an attacker wants to perform [ARP poisoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) without being connected through Ethernet to the (router\switch) s\he must use an [Aircrack](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/) adapter.

My question is, if the attacker somehow managed to plug his laptop to the router\switch, will s\he be able to use Cain and perform ARP poisoning and\or network sniffing against wireless clients which are connected to the router through WiFi?

Comment: ARP poisoning requires access to the local network. If you are behind a router, you are no longer on the local network.

Comment: I meant an ADSL or WIMAX router .

Comment: Once you are on the other side of a device (save a switch), you are no longer on the local network. You aren't seeing the MACs of the individual devices, but of the aggregating device.

Comment: To be clear: ARP poisoning is an attack against the local switch, nothing else. It's not necessary with a hub and will not work through a router.